# How to remove Service Principal Instance of a Multi Tenant Application from azure AD after user opts to unsubscribe service

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-graph-api

How do I manage Azure app registration consent after user unsubscribes a certain service I would like to remove the consents provided by the user from his azure ad tenant programmatically. what are the options?

we can inform tenant to remove service principal like below. but that again requires other permissions..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the permissions required for the delete service principal operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

- Delegated: Application.ReadWrite.All
- Application: Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy or Application.ReadWrite.All

Granting any of these permissions seems unlikely from most organizations as they would allow your application to create more applications in their tenant.
I'm not sure if a multi-tenant app becomes an owner of the service principal in another tenant, though I doubt it.

Personally I would make guidance for the users' admins and/or direct to some documentation from Microsoft.
For example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/delete-application-portal?tabs=http&pivots=portal

Comment: This seems to be the only way.. I was looking for smooth transition like just click a unregister .. and process takes care of the rest.